# Поворот изображения, всё перепробовал, получается дичь(

Tags: c++, изображения

Сначала попробовал просто через Xnew=sinA*Xold+cosA*Yold(не помню в каком порядке косинус/синус, сейчас неважно), потом через хорду пытался на бумажке, но там с углом проблемы были, в итоге сейчас через радиус-вектор делаю и почти получается. Изображение поворачивается, НО!!! Оно постоянно растет! И как я ни пытался (домножать на коэффициент "старые координаты/новые координаты" или просто делить на число, никак не получается убрать увеличение =(( 
В итоге мой кораблик растет до бесконечности. Что делать?

Вот так вкратце выглядит поворот:

```
if(this->shuttle.body[i].XY.X > this->shuttle.center.X)
       {
         angleB = atan((this->shuttle.body[i].XY.Y - this>shuttle.center.Y) / (this->shuttle.body[i].XY.X - this->shuttle.center.X));
        this->shuttle.body[i].XY.X = this->shuttle.body[i].XY.X + (rast * cos(angleB + TURN_PLAYER_SHIP));//считаю
        //корректировка 
        this->shuttle.body[i].XY.X = this->shuttle.body[i].XY.X * rast / Rasst(this->shuttle.center, this->shuttle.body[i].XY);
        this->shuttle.body[i].XY.Y = this->shuttle.body[i].XY.Y + (rast * sin(angleB + TURN_PLAYER_SHIP));//считаю
         //корректирую
        this->shuttle.body[i].XY.Y = this->shuttle.body[i].XY.Y * rast / Rasst(this->shuttle.center, this->shuttle.body[i].XY);
                    }
                    else if(this->shuttle.body[i].XY.X < this->shuttle.center.X)
                    {// АРКТГ ОТ - Пи/2 до пи/2, поэтому для Х меньше Х центра(отрицательные числа) нужно вычесть один ПИ
                        angleB = atan((this->shuttle.body[i].XY.Y - this->shuttle.center.Y) / (this->shuttle.body[i].XY.X - this->shuttle.center.X))-3.14;
                        this->shuttle.body[i].XY.X = this->shuttle.body[i].XY.X + (rast * cos(angleB + TURN_PLAYER_SHIP));//считаю
                        //корректировка 
                        this->shuttle.body[i].XY.X = this->shuttle.body[i].XY.X * rast / Rasst(this->shuttle.center, this->shuttle.body[i].XY);
                        this->shuttle.body[i].XY.Y = this->shuttle.body[i].XY.Y + (rast * sin(angleB + TURN_PLAYER_SHIP));//считаю
                        //корректирую
                        this->shuttle.body[i].XY.Y = this->shuttle.body[i].XY.Y * rast / Rasst(this->shuttle.center, this->shuttle.body[i].XY);
                    }
                    else// ==0
                    {
                        angleB = 3.14;//это ПИ, потому что 180 градусов
                        this->shuttle.body[i].XY.X = this->shuttle.body[i].XY.X + (rast * cos(angleB + TURN_PLAYER_SHIP));//считаю
                        //корректировка 
                        this->shuttle.body[i].XY.X = this->shuttle.body[i].XY.X * rast / Rasst(this->shuttle.center, this->shuttle.body[i].XY);
                        this->shuttle.body[i].XY.Y = this->shuttle.body[i].XY.Y + (rast * sin(angleB + TURN_PLAYER_SHIP));//считаю
                        //корректирую
                        this->shuttle.body[i].XY.Y = this->shuttle.body[i].XY.Y * rast / Rasst(this->shuttle.center, this->shuttle.body[i].XY);
                }
```

Comment: Попробуйте погуглить по запросу "алгоритм поворота изображения", там много есть вариантов, и это не праздный вопрос. Я если найду какую-нибудь удачную ссылку - скину...

Comment: и да, то, что ваша картинка после каждого поворота растёт - это нормально, если вы хотите, чтобы не росла, после поворота необходимо изменить ей размер (это второй алгоритм), оба алгоритма делаются через обратное преобразование (ответ может напишу попозже, если до меня никто не напишет, сейчас просто некогда)

Comment: у меня картинка не  какого-то конкретного размера, а я создал класс, который имеет "тело" из кучи сочетаний координаты точки+ цвет, таким образом получается кораблик, который я пытаюсь поворачивать в реальном времени в игре.

Comment: изначальная идея (делать через матрицу поворота) была правильной, а вот указанная формула — нет...

Comment: да неважно я написал тут по памяти быстро, там было естественно ещё с центром и т.д.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Нашёл решение, каждый раз делю координаты (из которых вычтены координаты центра, вокруг которого происходит вращение) на 1.975 в степени количества поворотов. То есть если я поворачиваю изображение на какой-то угол 3 раза, то координаты "разъехались" на 1.975 в степени 3.
Скорее всего это число зависит от угла поворота, но в общем это работает.

Comment: Плохой, негодный костыль, ведущий к накоплению погрешности.
Нужно всегда трансформировать исходное изображение.

Comment: нет у меня ничего не накапливается потому что я зациклил поворот - если на 360 градусов, то все возвращается к начальному варианту

Comment: Вы сравнивали побитово?

Comment: у меня нет необходимости побитово полной идентичности, это просто игра и я поворачиваю кораблик...

Comment: Тогда учтите, что через пару-тройку часов ваш кораблик может сильно похорошеть.

Comment: я ЗАЦИКЛИЛ поворот, хелоу